MacOS Preview redaction tool breaks PGFPlots graphics
Using MacOS's built in file viewer Preview, I am attempting to redact information in a document built with LaTeX, containing graphs from PGFPlots. However, saving the file after using the redaction tool screws up the graphics. Graph axes are gone, and plotted curves are closing for some reason.
Before:
After:
This is almost assuredly a bug with how preview is handling these graphics - and I'm not seeking help with a MacOS bug, don't worry - but is there anything special about graphics generated by PGFPlots that would cause this edge case problem? My first thought was that the curves are missing some piece of instruction that tells them they don't need to close, but that doesn't explain the damage to axes and other straight line vector graphics in the document.

Have you tried something other than Preview? It has been seen before that it messes up PDFs generated from LaTeX. Many years ago we saw that the line infractions and sqrts disappeared when a PDF had been filtered through Preview.

This is not an edge case - it happens for simple code as \documentclass[tikz]{standalone} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \node {test}; \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1); \end{tikzpicture} \end{document} . The problematic pdf code is generated by mac preview so it is unfortunately not related to LaTeX. I do not know how to analyse (binary) pdf or how to debug preview.
